# Проблема с построением дерева react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

у меня такая проблема. Я получаю с сервера массив обьектов, потом на основе их рисую дерево с помощью этой функции.

```
import { uniqBy, keyBy, cloneDeep, forEach, find } from 'lodash';

export const createTreeFromList = costCenters => {
  if (!costCenters || !costCenters.length) return [];
  const costCentersMap = keyBy(cloneDeep(costCenters), 'ID');
  let root = [];

  forEach(costCentersMap, curCostCenter => {
    const { parentID, archived } = curCostCenter;
    if (parentID) {
      if (!costCentersMap[parentID].children) {
        costCentersMap[parentID].children = [];
      }

      if (archived && curCostCenter.children) {
        const match = find(costCentersMap, { ID: curCostCenter.parentID });
        if (!match.children.length) {
          match.children = [...curCostCenter.children];
        }
        match.children = [...match.children, ...curCostCenter.children];
        curCostCenter.children = [];
      }
      const { children } = costCentersMap[parentID];

      children.push(curCostCenter);
    } else {
      root = [curCostCenter];
    }
  });
  return root;
};
```

Если обьект с флагом archived : true. То всех его детей мы переносим в родителя. Но на какой то из итерации по колекции `costCentersMap[parentID].children` возвращается undefined и падает ошибка. Может, кто-то подскажет как решить эту проблему. И чтоб все дерево рисовалось нормально.
Данные текстом

```
{
 ID: "08547950-04a2-4c60-abfd-c793b368a742"
 archived: false
 name: "The Science Guy"
 parentID: "545f15a1-6cee-4888-959d-d00ad2407335"
 spenderIDs: (2) ["5e502651cc5c280d9a9a41ad", "5e507ef3dbae960d9d194604"]
}
```

А это один из элементов в колекции:

```
1db392b0-36e4-4fde-9e2c-aecc01b7bcbb: {
 ID: "1db392b0-36e4-4fde-9e2c-aecc01b7bcbb"
 archived: false
 children: [{…}]
 name: "SCRUM"
 parentID: "545f15a1-6cee-4888-959d-d00ad2407335" 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пример данных текстом бы

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov добавил текстом

Answer (score 1):

Видимо есть элемент с каким-то `parentID`, который среди `ID` (еще/уже/совсем) не значится.
Бросьте исключение, посмотрите для начала:

```
const parent = costCentersMap[parentID]
if(!parent) throw new Error("inconsistent parentID ("+parentID+")")
```

Попробуйте не менять данные по месту, а формировать просто новую структуру на выходе, без архивных нод. Так, возможно, сложней ошибиться

Comment: т. е. я бы не стал опираться на порядок обхода `costCentersMap`, и одновременно читать из и писать в структуру, которую обходим.

Answer (score 0):

Почему так сложно?
Для начала там где у вас undefined, попробуйте использовать lodast/get

Пример:

```
const children = get(costCentersMap, 'parentID', {});
```

Comment: Не стоит. От того, что оно перестанет падать проблема не решится. Там нарушена целостность данных -- ссылка на парента, которого нет. Будет показывать ошибочные данные.

Comment: иногда null/undefined это валидный объект который может быть а может и не быть и на такой случай лучше использовать get или новый синтаксис js с точкой и вопросом

Comment: Иногда бывает, хороший новый синтаксис придумали. А конкретно тут не надо огрызки под коврик прятать.